# Unity rotate while moving forward

Tags: c#, rotation, unity-game-engine

I have the following code for my 2D game, it makes object randomly wonder on the screen. What I am having issues with, is when an object looks at the point it is going to, I would like it to rotate as it moves forward. What is happening now, is it rotates instantly to the point it is going towards. So, how can I get it to rotate slowly and move forward at the same time?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Wonder : MonoBehaviour {

    protected Vector2 wayPoint;
    protected float speed;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        speed = gameObject.GetComponent<Move>().playerSpeed;
        wonder();
    }

    void wonder(){
        wayPoint = Random.insideUnitCircle * 10;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        Vector2 dir = wayPoint - new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y);
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2(dir.y, dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0,Mathf.Atan2 (dir.y, dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90));
        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, wayPoint, Time.deltaTime * speed);
        float magnitude = (new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y) - wayPoint).magnitude;
        if(magnitude < 3){
            wonder();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an example Image:

[image: Ship Rotation]

So, once the ship gets to its point another will be created and it will move there. I am thinking I will have to have a list of 5+ points, then calculate the arch the ship needs to take adding new points as the ship hits a way point then removing old ones after. I am not sure how to do this though...

Answer (score 0):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Wander : MonoBehaviour {

    protected Vector3 velocity;
    protected Vector2 waypoint;
    protected float speed;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        speed = gameObject.GetComponent<Move>().playerSpeed;
        RandomizeWaypoint();
    }

    void RandomizeWaypoint(){
        waypoint = Random.insideUnitCircle * 10;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp( transform.position, waypoint, ref velocity, Time.deltaTime * speed );
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis( Mathf.Atan2( velocity.y, velocity.x ) * Mathf.Rad2Deg, Vector3.forward );
        if( Vector3.Distance( transform.position, waypoint ) < 3 ){
            RandomizeWaypoint();
        }
    }
}
```

Untested. Vector3.SmoothDamp can be pretty handy. Note the spelling also.

Comment: @Ryan End up figuring this out?